# Laravel - Using cached HTML for multiple languages?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, varnish, cloudflare

On our website, we support a number of languages (English, Spanish, French, etc).  All pages have the same url, regardless of language, as language is managed via a cookie (user_language). So for instance, a product page might be referenced via /products/id (with an optional slug). Search results can be returned via /search/keywords.

I really wanted to cache all html content (in varnish or CloudFlare) and then present the dynamic data via JavaScript (for instance if the user is logged in, in the top corner present their name, otherwise show a Sign In/Sign Up link). This works well until I bumped against the language issue. I'd like to avoid hitting Laravel for cached pages as much as possible to avoid the minimum 250ms or so boot time. Is this possible?

Comment: So, you want to store the translation in local and show accordingly (without touching db)?

Comment: Basically I want to see if any technology or method exists, that will display the proper cached content depending on the values in the cookies.
Value such as language, current city, etc.